# How do I retrieve a parameter into a f.text_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to pass a parameter into my f.text_field but I keep receiving an error. "wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)"

```
<%= f.text_field :location, params[:location],  placeholder: "Enter Zipcode", class: "form-control" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def edit
  @city = City.find_by(id: params[:id])
end

<%= form_for(@city, :html => { :multipart => true, :class => "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :location, class: "form-control", required: :required, placeholder: "Enter Zipcode" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.text_field :location,  placeholder: "Enter Zipcode", value: params[:location], class: "form-control" %>
```